# challenge certificate behind nginx reverse proxy .well-known path

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, cert-manager

Help with ACME HTTP01 Let's Encrypt challenge please.

i'm trying to get certificate for domain behind proxy.

my config:

```
upstream kube-ingress-https {
    # The least number of active connections
    least_conn;
        server 172.22.16.3:443 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=300;
    }

server {
    listen 443;

    proxy_protocol on;
    proxy_pass kube-ingress-https;
}
```

my scheme: `WORLD ====> NGINX (reverse proxy) ==============> K8S ingress(cert manager)`

cert-manager shows: `Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code '502', expected '200'`

```
curl -I -k https://k8s-dash.domain.kz/.well-known/acme-challenge/pXy1kENDkrXpGNKLeyCc8huIfgUILzjErxiYhj80mxI
HTTP/2 502
date: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 06:55:51 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 150
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true


curl -I -k https://k8s-dash.mydomain.kz
HTTP/2 200
date: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 06:55:58 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 1338
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
last-modified: Fri, 15 Oct 2021 07:41:12 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found a solution:

i've delete ingress annotation: `acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"`